# Error in Hadoop Example

Tags: java, hadoop

**I am using hadoop1.1.1, while i am trying to execute wordcount example then i am getting eof exception while file in present on specified location.**

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Call to
>   localhost/127.0.0.1:9100 failed on local exception:
>   java.io.EOFException
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.wrapException(Client.java:1144)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1112)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
>           at $Proxy1.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:411)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createRPCNamenode(DFSClient.java:135)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.(DFSClient.java:276)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.(DFSClient.java:241)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:100)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1411)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:66)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1429)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:254)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:123)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:238)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:187)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(FileInputFormat.java:352)
>           at WordCountDriver.main(WordCountDriver.java:32)
>           Caused by: java.io.EOFException
>           at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.receiveResponse(Client.java:848)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:786)

```
Please help.
```

Comment: post the command that generated this error

Comment: Hi Vaddeman, I configure example project in eclipse and run java file as run on hadoop. while hadoop is running at localhost which i run through CYGWIN.